# Specifying output location when assembling an Android project with Gradle via Terminal?

Tags: android, command-line, terminal, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to automate the build and upload process for a signed APK of an Android app without using Android Studio, so I'm running everything in Terminal. The first command is:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Which generates an unsigned, unaligned APK in the /APP NAME/build/outputs/apk folder. However, since APP NAME won't be the same for every app, I can't just hard code the location of the output file into the next step of signing it. Are there any arguments I can use with the gradlew command to specify an output directory and file name of my choice?

Comment: `assembleRelease` signs the app - what additional steps are you doing to the final APK?

Comment: After signing the app, it needs to be zipaligned and then uploaded to a server.

Comment: Hi , have you found the way to specify an output location upon assembling with terminal ?

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833297/how-to-define-apk-output-directory-when-using-gradle

Answer (score 2):

There is no such command to specify the output.But you can write a script to make this possible.As you have got the `/build/outputs/app-release.apk`, you can copy and rename it to everywhere you want.

Comment: where can he get output path? If you know the answer you are welcome to answer my similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137571/get-build-folder-path-for-android-studio-project-via-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

you can dynamically append some script to that build file(build.gradle) to set the `buildDir` of any project.

for example:

```
allprojects {
  buildDir = System.properties['user.home']+"/"+project.name;
}
```