# Get build folder path for Android Studio project via bash script

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-studio, gradle

In my bash script I can build my Android Studio project like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

That creates `.apk` file in project's build folder but I don't know the path to that folder inside my script.
Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a line 'finding' it-

```
path=`find ./ -name "*.apk"`
echo "$path"
```

If you want the absolute path-

```
path=`find ./ \`pwd\` . -name "*.apk"`
echo "$path"
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but when there's more than one apk files I should sort them by date and hope that's the one. Let's see if there's a more reliable solution and if not I'll mark the answer

Comment: You're not getting enough attention for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's counting views for the question I post the final version of the solution suggested by [@Chem-man17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6029161/chem-man17)

```
# ---------------- Copy .apk file to output folder -----------------------
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"
APK_FILE=`find ${PWD}/app/build/apk -type f -name "*.apk" -printf '%T@ %p\n' \
| sort -k 1nr \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/^[^ ]* //'`
APK_NAME=`echo $APK_FILE | xargs -I{} basename {}`
mv $APK_FILE $OUTPUT_DIR
echo "---  Created file: $OUTPUT_DIR/$APK_NAME"
```

Basically it sorts `.apks` in build folder by date and grabs the most recent