# Is it possible to define path for Generated .apk in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I am using studio version 2.2.0 and in App -> Build -> outputs, is the default path for generated .apk.

Is it possible that I had make some predefined path and studio automatically generate apk there??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to change the default path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280937/27095803

Answer (score 1):

firstly put this in your build.gradle file:

```
 android {
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputFile = file(outputDirectory)
}
}
```

then put this for the case project cleans:

```
task cleanNewPath(type: Delete) {
delete outputDirectory
}

clean.dependsOn(cleanNewPath)
```