# How to change the default output folder for generated apk files?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, gluon-mobile, buildship

When I use the gradle task to create an android `.apk` file it outputs it the the `build\javafxports\android` folder of the project (both the regular and unaligned files). I couldn't find a setting to change the output folder.

When I export a `jar` in eclipse I can specify a destination folder. How can I do that with `apk` files too?

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Mark/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833297/how-to-define-apk-output-directory-when-using-gradle#23280937)?

Comment: @MiroMarkaravanes thanks but the syntax seems different from what I have. can you help me convert it? I added my gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jfxmobile plugin allows changing the path where the apk will be created.

Use `installDirectory`:

```
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        installDirectory = file('/full/path/of/custom/folder')
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Be aware that the folder should exist before running `android` task. Currently the plugin manages that for the default installation folder (removing it, and the apk, if exists and creating it again on every run). So you have to do it yourself, otherwise the task will skip it.

*EDIT*

The list of global variables that are intended to be modified if necessary are [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.1.0/#_properties_3), but the full list of variables currently included in the plugin can be found in the plugin [source code](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/3c05cb8ea7e131f82b650bf87e1721aac897987e/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/AndroidExtension.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Variables like `installDirectory` are used internally by the plugin and they are initialized with a default value, perform some actions like deleting the previous directory and creating it again (so Gradle performs the task). In case of overriding, these actions won't be executed, so you should take care of that yourself (or create a task for that).

Comment: thanks. is that option supposed to be listed here http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.1.0/#_properties_3?

Comment: No, it is not listed there, as it is not initially intended to be overridden. That's why you have to take care of removing it's content.

Comment: ok. is there a list then of all the options somewhere? like how did you know about that one? i prefer to read than ask every single thing.

Comment: Go to the source... It is open! [Here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/3c05cb8ea7e131f82b650bf87e1721aac897987e/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/AndroidExtension.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) you can find all the global variables that you can modify externally on your script. Some of them are intended for that and are listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the standard **android plugin** to change the directory of the generated APKs:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = file("/some/dir/" + variant.name + "/" + archivesBaseName + ".apk")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not valid syntax. see the comments on the question. thanks though.