# How to build an APK into a particular directory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I have a project that has multiple modules:

```
MyProject
    module1  
    module2
```

I would like to generate the APK for module 2.

module 2 has the following instructions in its **build.gradle**:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        output.outputFile = new File("../module1/src/main/assets", "module2.apk")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to build the APK into module1's assets directory.

In **module1** build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    module1 {
        applicationId "com.myapp.module1"
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    module2 {
        applicationId "com.myapp.module2"
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

I build module1 APK (`**Android Studio -> Build -> Build APK**`), but I get the module2 APK built in **/media/user/path/to/project/dir/MyProject/module1/build/outputs/apk**. The APK also gets assigned an undesirable APK name which is a combination of **module1** and **module2**, that is **module1-module2-debug.apk**

How can I build module2 into module1's assets directory with the original apk name still being maintained, that is module2.apk?

Comment: try  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833297/how-to-define-apk-output-directory-when-using-gradle